# Trying to define a many-to-many relation with a pivot model in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, pivot, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

Trying this for hours now and I don't see the error. I have a model 'User' and a model 'Round'. I want to define a n:m-relation with a model 'Flight' as pivot model.

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

use Spatie\Image\Manipulations;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail, HasMedia
{

    use Notifiable;
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    /*
    .....
    */

    public function rounds() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Round::class)->using(Flight::class);
    }

}
```

Round.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Round extends Model
{

    /* 
    .....
    */

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(Flight::class);
    }

}
```

Flight.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Flight extends Pivot
{

    public $incrementing = true;

    /*
    .....
    */

}
```

I made several migrations and seeder.

RelationSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Round;

class RelationSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        
        $round = Round::find(1);

        $round->users()->sync([1]);
        
    }
}
```

When running `artisan migrate:refresh --seed` all tables are created as expected, but the following error occurs on seeding

*SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tour.round_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `round_user` where `round_id` = 1)*

Obviously Laravel is looking for a standard named pivot-table and not for the desired flights-table.

I am using Laravel 8 in a Docker-Container with Sail.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. With using the pivot model, the name conventions for the intermediate table stay valid. It works with

```
public function rounds() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Round::class, 'flights')->using(Flight::class); 
}
```

and same thing in the inverse definition

```
public function users() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'flights')->using(Flight::class); 
}
```

Thank you everybody who is helping here - I solved 1000s of problems reading your posts!